# Get accountID when creating lead in Dynamics CRM

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I have a plugin that triggers when I'm creating a `lead` and want to get the `ID` for the account the `lead` is related to `parentaccountid`. I'm able to print `"subject"` for the `lead` but when it comes to `"parentaccountid"` I get the message `"Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference"`, I'm guessing it's `null`? Weird thing is that when I'm looking at the lead record in FetchXML Builder there's a value in `parentaccountid`.

```
Guid leadId = new Guid(context.OutputParameters["id"].ToString());

ColumnSet cols = new ColumnSet(
new String[] { "subject", "parentaccountid" });

var retrievedLead = service.Retrieve("lead", leadId, cols);
tracingService.Trace(retrievedLead["subject"].ToString());

var accountId = retrievedLead["parentaccountid"];

tracingService.Trace(accountId.ToString());
```

Comment: I can't remember the syntax off the top of my head but I think you may need to simply put something like `var accountId = retrievedLead["parentaccountid"].Id;`. As it is you're retrieving an EntityReference that has multiple properties, putting `.Id` on the end specifies you want the `ID`.

Comment: @Equalsk Doesn't work, I have also tried with (EntityReference)entity["parentaccoundid"];

Comment: Did the second option in Arun's answer below work? It looks correct to me but I'm currently unable to test it which is why I'm only commenting.

Comment: @Equalsk It worked, problem solved.

Comment: Yeah, as soon as I saw his answer I realised I'd forgotten the cast. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below syntax to get the value.

```
EntityReference lookupRef = retrievedLead.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("parentaccountid");

if (lookupRef != null) 
      Guid accountId = lookupRef.Id;
```

Or

```
var accountId = ((EntityReference)retrievedLead["parentaccountid"]).Id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the below code

```
Guid ContactId = ((EntityReference)retrievedLead.Attributes["parentaccountid"]).Id;
string PrimaryContact   = ((EntityReference)retrievedLead.Attributes["parentaccountid"]).Name;
```